# string conversion with number

Tags: string, ada

shift function should shift characters according to the number is given

```
   function shift_char(c: Character; n:Integer) return Character is
      I : Integer;
   begin
        if Is_Lower(c) then
            I:= ((((Character'Pos(c) rem 26) + n) mod 26) + 97);
        elsif Is_Upper(c) then
            I:= ((((Character'Pos(c) rem 26) + n) mod 26) + 65);
        end if;

      return Character'val(I);
   end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher#Example), you first need to map the lowest character in each range to zero. Instead of `rem 26`, *subtract* the position of the initial character as shown in the variation below:

```
function Shift_Char (C : Character; N : Integer) return Character is
   Lower_A : constant Integer := Character'Pos (Lower'First);
   Upper_A : constant Integer := Character'Pos (Upper'First);
   I       : Integer          := Character'Pos (C);
begin
   if Is_Lower (C) then
      I := ((((I - Lower_A) + N) mod 26) + Lower_A);
   end if;
   if Is_Upper (C) then
      I := ((((I - Upper_A) + N) mod 26) + Upper_A);
   end if;
   return Character'Val (I);
end Shift_Char;
```

Console:

```
generated single_key is : 25
generated multi_keys list is : 16 8 25 11

before encryption with caesar: Ada Is Cool
encrypted:Zcz Hr Bnnk
decrypted: Ada Is Cool
before encryption with vigenere: Ada Is Cool
encrypted: Qlz Ti Knzb
decrypted: Ada Is Cool
```

Comment: Oh, I can see what was wrong with mine thank you!
Your solution is perfect!